# Multiple definition class in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

Help me out here. I don't know what I'm missing.
I have this code in my arduino IDE

```
#include "Foo2.h"
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

And I have five files: Foo.h, Foo.cpp, Foo2.h, Foo3.cpp and Foo.h

**Foo.h**

```
#ifndef Foo_H
#define Foo_H

class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo();

    public:
    bool Fooa();
    bool Foob();
};
#endif
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo()
{
    
}

bool Foo::Foob()
{
    return true;
}
```

**Foo2.h**

```
#ifndef Foo2_H
#define Foo2_H
#define LIBRARY_VERSION 1.0.0
#include "Foo.h"
    
bool Foo::Fooa()
{
    return true;
}
#endif
```

**Foo3.h**

```
#ifndef Foo3_H
#define Foo3_H
#include "Foo2.h"

class Foo3
{
    public:
        Foo3();
        Foo _foo;
};
#endif
```

**Foo3.cpp**

```
#include "Foo3.h"

Foo3::Foo3()
{
}
```

And it is give me an error:

```
libraries\Foo\Foo3.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Foo::Fooa()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Foo::Fooa()'
sketch\kk2.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
```

what i'm doing wrong

regards,

Comment: Please show us "Foo3.cpp" that is mentioned in the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `Fooa()` to be defined in a header that can be included in more than one .cpp file, you would need to declare it as an inline function like so:

```cpp
#ifndef Foo_H
#define Foo_H

class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo();

    public:
    inline bool Fooa();
    bool Foob();
};
#endif
```

Alternately, you can provide the function definition directly inside class definition; this also makes the function `inline` despite not requiring the `inline` keyword.

Or if you want to keep `Fooa` as a non-inline function, you'd need to move the definition out of the header and into a .cpp file as you did with `Foob()`.

Making a function inline has a second effect beyond implying that you want a function's code to be generated at the call site; it informs the compiler (or more accurately the linker) to expect to see multiple definitions (that are required to be identical) of the code for the function.  Without that advanced noticed, you will get the `multiple definition of` error when a function definition is inserted into multiple .cpp file by way of an `#include`.

As a side note: `#include` is an automated form of copy-and-paste.  It logically plants the contents of another file (and all of its reachable `#include` uses transitively) into place where the `#include` directive appeared.  It does not behave the same way that many similar looking directives in other languages do.  E.g. `#include` does not behave like the `import` keyword does in say Java or python for example.

Comment: It didn't work adding the 'inline' keyword. I have edit part of my question, because I have other files too.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this [https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79641/problemm-with-the-mpu6050-library]. And I think that I have to figure out this problem first.

Comment: No, you were right it works. I have to put the 'inline' keyword in the Foo.h and Foo2.cpp